# LG Optimus S accelerometer accuracy always 0

Tags: android, accelerometer, lg, optimus

Does anybody own an LG Optimus S and seen a value for Sensor.accuracy that wasn't 0 (Sensor.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE)? We apparently need to test accuracy of the sensor events we are getting, but on my phone the accuracy is always 0 and wanted to see if it was a phone wide issue or if mine is busted or something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look to part lists of your phone, you will find that accelerometers built in are far away from reliable -  so there is always a lot of noise and little accuracy. Chips used in HTC Hero provide deliver 8 bit value for +/- 8G 
(hope this helps, even it is not LG specific)

Comment: Do you know where I can find a parts list for my phone?

Comment: You may get exact model by  just System.out(sensorObjectYouGotFromSensorManager) - at least this worked on HTC hero.  Most probably it will be something like Bosh Sensortec BMA 150 (you will not find anything expensive in a phone)

Comment: Hmm didn't know I could do that. Thanks.